# Weapon Sway Script messes up weapon rotation

Tags: c#, unity

So I'm in the process of learning Unity 5 and scripting in it. One thing I wanted to give a try was to make a simple weapon sway script like you see in games such as battlefield or csgo. After a bit of documentation I finally got a script going (see below).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WeaponSway : MonoBehaviour {

    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;
    float movementX;
    float movementY;
    float smooth = 3;
    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        movementX = mouseX * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        movementY = mouseY * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        Quaternion final = Quaternion.Euler(defaultposition.x * movementX, defaultposition.y * movementY, 0);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation,final,Time.deltaTime*smooth);

    }
}
```

However, for some reason the simple model of the weapon I'm using changes rotation and the weapon doesn't sway like intended. I can't see the problem in the script.

Here is a gif of what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vF4Y.jpg

Comment: You may have set the rotation too far.